# Embedded linux to read text and append it to another file

Tags: linux, embedded, text

I have an embedded linux system that has limited commands available. VI being the only text editor I found so far. I can run SH to run a script but again, limited abilities.

I need to ftpget a text file from a remote address, read said text file, then update a specific line that starts with syslocation in a different text file.

So:

```
text file 1 (snmpd.conf) has this on line 16: syslocation NO GPS INFO
text file 2 (gps.txt) has the GPS info on line 1: 51.5073509,-0.127758
```

If you have links on examples of updating this, I would be most thankful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `vi` configured to be able to be invoked as `ex`, which sounds exactly what you want. `ex` is `vi` in non-interactive mode. See the answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/457/does-ex-mode-have-any-practical-use

See also the answer here for practical examples: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-edit-files-non-interactively-e-g-in-pipeline

Both links themselves include many useful other links.

Comment: Thank you.

This is what I get: 
`ex: not found`

Comment: @CJDronePilot : One of the links discusses other possible options, such as `vi -s script-file-name`. Is that available to you? Try some of the examples there as a test.

Comment: Yeah, I may be out of luck.

`root:/> vi -s
vi: invalid option -- s
These features are available:
root:/>`

Comment: @CJDronePilot : OK, one more shot in the dark - Do you have `ed`? If not, why not do your editing in your shell script? Many basic versions of `sh` include features such as native substitution `${var/foo/bar}` and other related useful idioms.

Comment: Also, just to be thorough, did you check for `sed` and `awk`?

Comment: Tell me more about the `sh`

Comment: All of the others are not in this build:
`root:/> sed
sed: not found
root:/> awk
awk: not found
root:/> ed
ed: not found
root:/>`

Comment: @CJDronePilot : You tell me. There are many versions of the shell, and you seem to have a very limited system. Try typing `sh --version` to find what type and version of shell is installed, and then get a hold of its `man` page to read its capabilities, which will include its scripting commands. Write your script and if you have a problem, ask a separate specifc question here. Another option is to turn to the manufacturer or maintainer of the device on which the linux is embedded, and ask them what editors or scripting options exist.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your insight. Always appreciated.